# Best Practices for nesting controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When building nested folder structure on rails for controllers, for e.g `controllers/posts/bulk_controller.rb`, is the corresponding route always going to be `/post/:post_id/bulk`.

What I am essentially trying to do is create a controller with `:create` method that will create bulk posts (more than 1), the problem I am encountering is that now `:post_id` is always required in my route that is generated but I am not hitting the end point with a specific post in mind.

**EDIT**

I have done more research and I believe that if the resources are nested you'll have to send in an id of the parent resource.

My question has now changed to why it was done this way. It is always so interesting for me to learn how and why rails does things because it's often to solve problems you haven't thought of.

Extra points for directing me to the source code in rails where the routes are generated please.

Comment: Feels to me like you are looking for a [namespaced route](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-namespace) instead of a nested resource or you could use [`collection` routing](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-collection) to generate such routes.

Comment: Your routes are the external API your application provides to the outside world while your code organization  is an internal implementation detail. In most simple cases there is a direct correlation eg.  `/posts -> PostsController#index` but there are many many cases where this is not true. Take the popular Devise gem for example.

Comment: They have a decent, in-depth guide on the site. You'll find a good few answers there. - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Cough up the extra points -- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dcb1d1f4c4987c3352f8c5f94bb44393b0f18252/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb, https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dcb1d1f4c4987c3352f8c5f94bb44393b0f18252/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/route.rb.